# How to get correct distance between tracked entity and camera in Cesium Js?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to get distance between an entity and camera in meters. To achieve that I'm passing cartesian3 positions of camera and entity in `Cesium.Cartesian3.distanceSquared`. It seems distance is calculating properly when the entity is not being tracked. But Tracked entity distance seems higher even though the camera is nearly moving along with the tracked entity.[image]

I'm not getting how to get correct distance between any entity (tracked/without tracked) and camera.

Entity can be anywhere on earth or in air and distance should not be the travelling distance.

```
viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function (clock) {
  let epos = entity.position.getValue(clock.currentTime);
  let campos = viewer.camera.position;
  let distancebetween = Cesium.Cartesian3.distanceSquared(epos, campos);
  if (viewer.trackedEntity){
    console.log("Tracked:" + distancebetween);
  }else{
    console.log("NotTracked:" + distancebetween);
  }
});
```

Here is the Sandcastle [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck using the camera's "world position" rather than its position within its own current coordinate frame.  For example:

```js
let campos = viewer.camera.positionWC;
```

I don't recommend using fields starting with an underscore, such as `_positionCartographic`.  Those are intended to be private variables, and can change between Cesium releases without any notice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why distance between camera position Cartesian3 value and entity Cartesian3 value is not correct. However, I have sorted out that converting Camera's Cartographic position to Cartesian3 is calculating correct distance.

Replaced:

```
let campos = viewer.camera.position;
```

with

```
let camPosCart3 = Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(viewer.camera._positionCartographic);
```

and it is working fine.

It would be appreciable if someone would have any explanation on this.

Regards,